# Using 'changing' LayoutTransition type in a ListVIew has no effect

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, layouttransition

In Android, I am currently attempting to create a list whose items change height when clicked, with all views below that item animating up or down depending on the height change. I have had success using the following code with a 'list' of items inside a LinearLayout:

```
LayoutTransition t = new LayoutTransition();
t.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
myLinearLayout.setLayoutTransition(t);
```

However, when I try to apply this LayoutTransition to a ListView instead of a LinearLayout, the height of the clicked item animates but all the items below it instantly jump to the new position. How can I get the rest of the views to animate with the clicked item?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this easily (and there is better way to do this). The position of the ListView rows are fixed and controlled by the AdapterView.

I have made a little research. Firstly, to fire the CHANGING animation you can't remove your row as usually (deleting the item from adapter). You have to hide your item by setting visibility to GONE then it will fire the DISAPPEARING animation and consequently the CHANGING animation. BUT to make the CHANGING animation available you have to request layout (on ListView) at any time when you are changing the height of the row. On the end of animation you can delete your item from the adapter and redraw the ListView. Additionally you can make your IDs of rows stable with their positions to not redrawing all ListView. I tried to do it this way but there were complications on various versions of Android API.

In the end, it is possible to implement animations on ListView using LayoutTransition BUT this is complicated and not worthy from implementation point of view. It is sufficent for simple cases but not for more complicated animations in ListView. To implement the animation, it is better to use already cooked component: 
https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations